# When I publish a c# app, how do I get the setup to auto request admin privileges?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a simple single site browser using visual studio 2022 in c#.  I added the pre-requisite webview2.  When I publish the file it creates the setup.exe and it does start the webview2 install but then it fails because it doesn't have admin privileges.  I am not talking about my app but rather the setup.exe that visual studio 2022 creates.  How can I escalate just that without requesting admin to run my app every time?

I know they can right click the setup.exe and run as administrator but not everyone is going to know to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle or change the consent dialog of UAC (User Account Control), that is the point of having UAC.

As far as i know, you cannot even call it manually to ask for admin privileges.

you do have 2 other options:

Option 1  -
Ask for admin privileges every time the program runs by adding the following to your manifest file

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Option 2 -
Check that you have admin privileges before running that specific code block

```
[PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
private static void YourCode()
{
  Console.WriteLine("User is an Administrator");
}
```